# Nav tag is hidden

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to web designing and upon doing some exercises, I encountered this problem: My `nav` tag was also hidden when I set header tag display to none. I tried adding `display:block` and `clear: display` to `nav` tag but did nothing. I read that `position: fixed` is hiding `nav` tag but as much as possible I do not want to remove it. I have not studied javascript yet, but let us say I did it with javascript, will the same problem occur or not? Please help me with this and suggest better ways to do it. Pardon my ignorance.

Here's my code for reference:

```
#header{
    padding: 1.5px 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: -3%;
    margin-bottom: -4%;
    display: none;
} 

#nav{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: show;
}
```

Comment: It's maybe hidden behind an other element, try adding `z-index: 9999`

Comment: is your #nav inside #header ?

Comment: What's with this `display: show;` line? `display: show;` property doesn't exist.

Comment: Javascript is not the answer here. As noted above, your best bet is to put the HTML somewhere we can see it like jsfiddle.net. It's very hard to debug with just the CSS.

Comment: It's good that you are trying in Web Designing field, but post both your html and css code. And literally there is no display:show; in css.

Comment: As @Shl asks, is your nav in your header?  If it is it makes a big difference as your header is `display:none` so anything inside it will be hidden, you cannot set the child to display if their parent is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this CSS style :

```
#header{ position:relative;} 
#nav {display: block;}
```

Comment: Check your spelling. "relavtive"... you probably meant "relative". And this won't solve much since the questioner used the `display: none;` property inside the #header. If the #nav is placed inside the #header, than it means the #header and the #nav won't be displayed at all.